# Calculate difference date time for each record per month

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's suppose I have the following table.
How can I can separately calculate the delay for each month.

```
Req start_dt    end_dt
1   1/2/2017    3/5/2017
2   5/2/2017    7/6/2017
```

I want the result to be like the following table.

```
Req start_dt    end_dt     delay    MM
1   1/2/2017    3/5/2017    30      1
1   1/2/2017    3/5/2017    28      2
1   1/2/2017    3/5/2017    5       3
2   5/2/2017    7/6/2017    30      5
2   5/2/2017    7/6/2017    30      6
2   5/2/2017    7/6/2017    6       7
```

Comment: What logic are you using to get that result? What have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: For days simple minus should word: date1 - date2. To get months difference there is MONTHS_BETWEEN function.

Comment: I really cannot see any relationship between the dates and the values in the delay / MM columns.  The last three rows have the exact same dates and yet have differing delay and MM values.  What is your logic?

Comment: @AlexPoole Business needs.

Comment: @Nawaf - that is not at all helpful... your question doesn't tell us anything about the logic for how you get from a single row with a date range to multiple rows with the same range and some other numbers you haven't explained. I think I've figured it out but I shouldn't have to - your question should explain it. (It should also show the table data types, and show any dates in an unambiguous format - these seem to be MM/DD/YYYY, but again shouldn't have to guess/figure that out ourselves).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with correlated hierarchical queries:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44af9/25)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Req, start_dt, end_dt ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-02', DATE '2017-03-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2017-05-02', DATE '2017-07-06' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       LEAST( LAST_DAY( d.COLUMN_VALUE ), t.end_dt )
         - GREATEST( d.COLUMN_VALUE, t.start_dt ) + 1 AS delay,
       EXTRACT( MONTH FROM d.COLUMN_VALUE ) AS MM
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( t.start_dt, 'MM' ), LEVEL - 1 )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MONTHS_BETWEEN( t.end_dt, TRUNC( t.start_dt, 'MM' ) ) + 1
           ) AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST
         )
       ) d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44af9/25/0)**:

```
| REQ |             START_DT |               END_DT | DELAY | MM |
|-----|----------------------|----------------------|-------|----|
|   1 | 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-05T00:00:00Z |    30 |  1 |
|   1 | 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-05T00:00:00Z |    28 |  2 |
|   1 | 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-05T00:00:00Z |     5 |  3 |
|   2 | 2017-05-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-07-06T00:00:00Z |    30 |  5 |
|   2 | 2017-05-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-07-06T00:00:00Z |    30 |  6 |
|   2 | 2017-05-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-07-06T00:00:00Z |     6 |  7 |
```

Comment: Amazing it works fine. thanks till know I can't understand how your query is working I am trying to understand it. thanks again.

Comment: @Nawaf For each row in the table it will evaluate the hierarchical query to generate an array of months which overlap your range and will then `CROSS JOIN` that back to the correlated row so that there is one row for each month within each range.

Comment: How to calculate the delay if end_dt is null.

Comment: @Nawaf `NULL` is an unknown value - you cannot work out the difference between a known and an unknown value. If you want `SYSDATE` to be substituted for `NULL` values then just use `COALESCE( t.end_dt, SYSDATE )` instead of all the instances of `t.end_dt`.

Comment: Thanks i will try.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split your date ranges into multiple months, with the full range for intermediate months and partial ranges for the start and end months. One way to do that is with [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)

```
with rcte (req, start_dt, end_dt, period_start_dt, period_end_dt) as (
  select req, start_dt, end_dt, start_dt,
    case when trunc(end_dt, 'MM') = trunc(start_dt, 'MM') then end_dt
      else last_day(start_dt) end
  from your_table
  union all
  select req, start_dt, end_dt, add_months(trunc(period_start_dt, 'MM'), 1),
    case when trunc(end_dt, 'MM') = add_months(trunc(period_start_dt, 'MM'), 1) then end_dt
      else last_day(add_months(trunc(period_start_dt, 'MM'), 1) ) end
  from rcte
  where trunc(end_dt, 'MM') > trunc(period_start_dt, 'MM')
)
select req, start_dt, end_dt, period_start_dt, period_end_dt,
  period_end_dt - period_start_dt + 1 as delay,
  extract(month from period_start_dt) as mm
from rcte
order by req, period_start_dt, period_end_dt;

       REQ START_DT   END_DT     PERIOD_STA PERIOD_END      DELAY         MM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2017-01-02 2017-03-05 2017-01-02 2017-01-31         30          1
         1 2017-01-02 2017-03-05 2017-02-01 2017-02-28         28          2
         1 2017-01-02 2017-03-05 2017-03-01 2017-03-05          5          3
         2 2017-05-02 2017-07-06 2017-05-02 2017-05-31         30          5
         2 2017-05-02 2017-07-06 2017-06-01 2017-06-30         30          6
         2 2017-05-02 2017-07-06 2017-07-01 2017-07-06          6          7
```

The recursive CTE has an anchor member which gets the initial data from your table, and calculates the start and end of the first period. The period start is the original range start date; the period end is either the range end date (if it's in the same month), or the end of that month.

The recursive member then uses the values from the anchor and generates a new period, which will start at the beginning of the following month, and again end either at the original range end date or the end of that month.

Once you have those period start/end dates it's simple to calculate the difference using normal date subtraction. (I've left the period start/end dates in the output to try and make it a bit clearer; just remove from the final select list if you don't want them.)

---

Slightly simpler calculation for the period start/end dates:

```
with rcte (req, start_dt, end_dt, period_start_dt, period_end_dt) as (
  select req, start_dt, end_dt, start_dt, least(end_dt, last_day(start_dt))
  from your_table
  union all
  select req, start_dt, end_dt, add_months(trunc(period_start_dt, 'MM'), 1),
    least(end_dt, last_day(add_months(trunc(period_start_dt, 'MM'), 1)))
  from rcte
  where trunc(end_dt, 'MM') > trunc(period_start_dt, 'MM')
)
select req, start_dt, end_dt,
  period_end_dt - period_start_dt + 1 as delay,
  extract(month from period_start_dt) as mm
from rcte
order by req, period_start_dt, period_end_dt;

       REQ START_DT   END_DT          DELAY         MM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2017-01-02 2017-03-05         30          1
         1 2017-01-02 2017-03-05         28          2
         1 2017-01-02 2017-03-05          5          3
         2 2017-05-02 2017-07-06         30          5
         2 2017-05-02 2017-07-06         30          6
         2 2017-05-02 2017-07-06          6          7
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and clarification. unfortunately the code is not working I will try again to fix it. thanks again.

Comment: "Not working" also isn't very helpful. It seems to work with the sample data you gave.